# Is "I wish you have a nice weekend" a native expression?

Tags: grammaticality

Somebody said this to me, and to me it sounds strange but I can't figure out why. Yes it **is** correct, but I don't think I've ever heard anyone ever say this before, so I wanted to get a second opinion on whether anyone uses it and if not why not. It seems far more common to say "hope" rather than "wish", but is there a reason why? It seems "wish" may be more strong, but I'm not sure.

Should I correct them?

Comment: Natives just say “Have a nice weekend.”

Comment: Who told you “I wish you have a nice weekend”? A native speaker?

Comment: No - an English learner. @user66974

Comment: We say "I wish you a (nice weekend/happy birthday/merry Christmas)" meaning "I hope you will have a (...)" - so if you use _wish_ you don't need to include _have_.

Comment: Yes wishing people a merry Christmas/holiday is normal, but ... is it for weekends? I've only heard "have" , not "wish", and i feel there is a subtle difference

Comment: ***We wish you a merry Christmas*** is a "fixed expression", along with things like ***I wish you goodbye*** (a fixed expression still sometimes used when parting company with someone in a formal context). But it's not a "productive" format, so learners should avoid using variants that they haven't actually heard being used by native speakers. Say ***Have a nice weekend / Enjoy your birthday***, rather than ***I wish you a nice weekend / happy birthday***.

Comment: No, we can report that "I wished him a good weekend" but we wouldn't normally say to someone "I wish you a nice weekend". I was just explaining the grammatical difference between _I wish you a_ and _[I hope you] have a_

Answer (score 1):

It is not a phrase a native speaker would use, although most if not all native speakers would understand it.

As mentioned in comments, the more common phrase would be simply "**Have a nice weekend**," or perhaps "**I *hope* you have a nice weekend**."

"We/I wish you a merry Christmas" is a set phrase; "We/I wish you a happy Easter/New Year/birthday" would be more likely said as "We/I hope you have a happy Easter/New Year/birthday" (or simply "Happy Easter/New Year/birthday"). It is common to simply prefix the name of a holiday or other special day with "Happy" to form a greeting (except in the case of Christmas, in which case "Merry" is used instead). I have never heard just "Happy weekend," though.